# HTML Element Replacement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code in question, below, is supposed to replace every instance of, well, it's complicated, but basically it's going to take an IP on a page and turn it into a server name (as defined by me in my code). It kinda works in that it replaces some IPs - but only one per IP, so if there's more than one instance on a page, it only replaces one. How do I go about this?

```
var arrServerInstances = document.body.innerHTML.match('27015');

    if (arrServerInstances != null)
    {
        if (arrServerInstances.length > 0)
        {   
            //UK Servers
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.246.178:27015','Common Grounds D2 UK');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.246.174:27015','Assault 24/7 UK');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.246.176:27015','Officefest UK');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.246.175:27015','Dustfest UK');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.246.177:27015','London Gungame UK');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.246.179:27015','Dust 2 Deatchmatch UK');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('83.222.240.93:27015','Mad Hatter\'s TF2 Tea Party UK');
            //US Servers
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.164:27015','Dust/Office Deathmatch US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.169:27015','Zombiemod US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.165:27015','Dust 24/7 -aMs- US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.172:27015','CS 1.6 Gungame US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.239.31:27015','Crackhouse US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.166:27015','Iceworld 24/7 US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.170:27015','Mad as a TF2 Hatter US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.167:27015','Gungame Turbo US');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('76.74.236.168:27015','CS:S Iceworld 24/7 US');
        }
    }
```

P.S. This is the first thing I've ever written in Javascript, I'm a C, C++, Objective C, VBA (God forbid) programmer, so if there's an easier way to do this, please, don't be afraid to point it out.

Comment: FYI: Generally try to avoid `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.someModification...`. Every time you do that, the browser needs to entirely recreate the DOM. In your case, the DOM is being recreated 16 times. There are less destructive solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You've compiled a list of all strings that match "27015," now you need to loop through every one and compare against your list.

Try a "foreach" loop (kind of difficult in Javascript).
Or try a "while" loop.  You would pop each element off the list as you compare (and possibly alter) it, and then exit the loop when there are none left in the list.

I would use jQuery to help you out here, since it has a handy [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function, as well as making the editing of the DOM a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You use a regular expression for the replacement so that you can specify the `g` flag for global replacement:

```
s = s.replace(/83\.222\.246\.178:27015/g,'Common Grounds D2 UK');
```

You shouldn't get the HTML code of the body and put it back for each replacement. That means that for every replacement you create a string representation of every object in the body, then parse it back into elements again.

You can use the `indexOf` method to look for the first occurance of a string in another, instead of using a regular expression to get every occurance into an array.

```
// get HTML
var html = document.body.innerHTML;

var hasServerInstances = html.indexOf('27015') != -1;

if (hasServerInstances) {   
  //UK Servers
  html = html
    .replace(/83\.222\.246\.178:27015/g,'Common Grounds D2 UK')
    .replace(/83\.222\.246\.174:27015/g,'Assault 24/7 UK')
    .replace(/83\.222\.246\.176:27015/g,'Officefest UK')
    .replace(/83\.222\.246\.175:27015/g,'Dustfest UK')
    .replace(/83\.222\.246\.177:27015/g,'London Gungame UK')
    .replace(/83\.222\.246\.179:27015/g,'Dust 2 Deatchmatch UK')
    .replace(/83\.222\.240\.93:27015/g,'Mad Hatter\'s TF2 Tea Party UK');
  //US Servers
  html = html
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.164:27015/g,'Dust/Office Deathmatch US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.169:27015/g,'Zombiemod US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.165:27015/g,'Dust 24/7 -aMs- US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.172:27015/g,'CS 1.6 Gungame US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.239\.31:27015/g,'Crackhouse US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.166:27015/g,'Iceworld 24/7 US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.170:27015/g,'Mad as a TF2 Hatter US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.167:27015/g,'Gungame Turbo US')
    .replace(/76\.74\.236\.168:27015/g,'CS:S Iceworld 24/7 US');
  // put the HTML back
  document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
```

You can even use regular expressions to match multiple servers in a single replace:

```
// get HTML
var html = document.body.innerHTML;

var hasServerInstances = html.indexOf('27015') != -1;

if (hasServerInstances) {   
  //UK Servers
  html = html.replace(/83\.222\.246\.17[4-9]:27015/g, function(m){
    switch(m) {
      case '174': return 'Assault 24/7 UK';
      case '175': return 'Dustfest UK';
      case '176': return 'Officefest UK';
      case '177': return 'London Gungame UK';
      case '178': return 'Common Grounds D2 UK';
      case '179': return 'Dust 2 Deatchmatch UK';
    }
  });
  html = html.replace(/83\.222\.240\.93:27015/g,'Mad Hatter\'s TF2 Tea Party UK');
  //US Servers
  html = html.replace(/76\.74\.236\.1(6[4-9]|7[02]):27015/g, function(m){
    switch(m) {
      case '164': return 'Dust/Office Deathmatch US';
      case '165': return 'Dust 24/7 -aMs- US';
      case '166': return 'Iceworld 24/7 US';
      case '167': return 'Gungame Turbo US';
      case '168': return 'CS:S Iceworld 24/7 US';
      case '169': return 'Zombiemod US';
      case '170': return 'Mad as a TF2 Hatter US';
      case '172': return 'CS 1.6 Gungame US';
    }
  });
  html = html.replace(/76\.74\.239\.31:27015/g,'Crackhouse US');
  // put the HTML back
  document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var ips = {
  '83.222.246.178:27015':'Common Grounds D2 UK',
  '83.222.246.178:27015':'Common Grounds D2 UK',
  '83.222.246.178:27015':'Common Grounds D2 UK'
  // The rest of the ip adress go here
};

var text = document.body.innerHTML;
for(var i in ips)text=text.replace(RegExp(i,'g'),ips[i]);
document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the data from the code and process data from a data structure.

This new version has the following advantages:

1. It only sets the innerHTML back once which means there's only one DOM reparse and reflow rather than lots.
2. The data is put into a table and looped through rather than lots of copied lines of code.
3. This code will replace all occurrences of a given IP because of the addition of the "g" flag.
4. This code properly escapes the periods in the regular expression so that they only match a period instead of the usual regular expression wildcard character.
5. I've made it into a function so your variables aren't global
6. I've compressed the if comparison into one compound comparison
7. Removed the duplicate ":27015" from every string and put it once into the code

Here's the code:

```
function attachIpNames() {
    var str = document.body.innerHTML;
    var arrServerInstances = str.match('27015');
    if (arrServerInstances && arrServerInstances.length > 0) {
        var definitions = [
             //UK Servers
            '83.222.246.178', 'Common Grounds D2 UK',
            '83.222.246.174', 'Assault 24/7 UK',
            '83.222.246.176', 'Officefest UK',
            '83.222.246.175', 'Dustfest UK',
            '83.222.246.177', 'London Gungame UK',
            '83.222.246.179', 'Dust 2 Deatchmatch UK',
            '83.222.240.93',  'Mad Hatter\'s TF2 Tea Party UK',
            //US Servers
            '76.74.236.164', 'Dust/Office Deathmatch US',
            '76.74.236.169', 'Zombiemod US',
            '76.74.236.165', 'Dust 24/7 -aMs- US',
            '76.74.236.172', 'CS 1.6 Gungame US',
            '76.74.239.31',  'Crackhouse US',
            '76.74.236.166', 'Iceworld 24/7 US',
            '76.74.236.170', 'Mad as a TF2 Hatter US',
            '76.74.236.167', 'Gungame Turbo US',
            '76.74.236.168', 'CS:S Iceworld 24/7 US'
        ];

        var target;
        for (var i = 0; i < definitions.length; i+= 2) {
            target = definitions[i].replace(".", "\\.") + ":27015";         // get target and escape the period so it will match an actual period in the regex
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(target, "g"), definitions[i+1]);
        }
        document.body.innerHTML = str;
    }
}
```

If this were my code, I would try to narrow the replacement down to only targeted divs so that I didn't cause a reflow in the entire document and it would probably be faster too.